# Rails 4:register a person in my rails app through voice call verification

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twilio

Can you please share that how can i make a outbound call to a person who want to register in my Rails 4 application and make a verification through his voice(in short i want to register a person in my rails app through voice call verification), Is that possible with twillo or suggest some other way to do it?

Please suggest the step by step or suggest some tutorial/doc/video

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby

and

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/twiml

**Call and ask for verification:**

```
    require 'twilio-ruby'

    # build up a response
    response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Say 'hello there, enter verification code', :voice => 'alice'
      r.Dial :callerId => '+14159992222' do |d|
      r.Gather :numDigits => '5', :action => "/verify_code?id=#{id}", :method => 'get' do |g|
            g.Say 'Verified thankyou.' if verified?
          else
            # hangup or set behaviour
          end
        end
      end
    end

def verify_code
  @verification = Verification.where(verification_code: params[:id]).first

  if @verification
    #activate
  else
    # Handle errors
  end
end
```

Finally in your model you'll need code that generates the verification code, and verifies if it is confirmed

```
class Verification < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create -> { self[:verification_code] = rand.to_s[2..5] }
end
```